# InvalidArgumentError while Building a deep-CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I’m new to TensorFlow and python... 
I’m trying to build a deep CNN for cell image classification Hep-2 dataset. The data set consists of `13596` images and I’m using `8701` images as my training data for CNN. Also, I have.CSV file which consists of image ID and its cell-type. I extracted the content and using image_ID from .CSV file as my labels. Both training data and Image ID has been converted to `.astype(‘float32’)`. But, somehow I’m getting InvalidArgumentError which I have no idea what’s going on in there. 
I’ve posted my code and error, any tips or help would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

I'm new to Stack Overflow as well. sorry for my messy formatting.

My CODE:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD

def extract_labels(image_names, Original_Labels):
  temp = np.array([image.split('.')[0] for image in image_names])
  temp2 = np.array([j[0] for i in temp for j in Original_Labels if(int(i) == int(j[0]))])
  return temp2

def get_Labels():
  df=pd.read_csv('gt_training.csv', sep=',')
  labels = np.asarray(df)

  path = 'path..../training/'
  image_names_train = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.splitext(f)[-1] == '.png']

  return labels, image_names_train



Train_images = glob.glob('path.../training/*.png')
train_data = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in Train_images])

train_data = train_data.astype('float32')
train_data /= 255

#getting labels from .csv file for training data
labels, image_names_train = get_Labels()
train_labels = extract_labels(image_names_train, labels)
train_labels = train_labels.astype('float32')
print(train_labels.shape)

train_data = train_data.reshape(train_data.shape[0],78,78,1) #reshaping into 4-Dim
input_shape = (78, 78, 1) #1 because the provided dataset is in grey scale 


#Adding pooling, dense layers to an an non-optimized empty CNN
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(6, kernel_size=(7,7),activation = tf.nn.tanh, input_shape = input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(4,4),activation = tf.nn.tanh))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3),activation = tf.nn.tanh))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3, 3)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(150, activation = tf.nn.tanh, kernel_regularizer = keras.regularizers.l2(0.00005)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(6, activation = tf.nn.softmax))

#setting an optimizer with a given loss function
opt = SGD(lr = 0.01, momentum = 0.9)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(x = train_data, y = train_labels, epochs = 10, batch_size = 77)
```

The error message I got:

```
six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from

InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 13269 which is outside the valid range of [0, 6).  Label values: 8823 3208 9410 5223 8817 3799 6588 1779 1371 5017 9788 9886 3345 1815 5943 37 675 2396 4485 9528 11082 12457 13269 5488 3250 12896 13251 1854 10942 6287 6232 2944
     [[node loss_24/dense_55_loss/sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at C:\Users\vardh\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_676176]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Comment: I've already Mentioned this as an answer to my post like around 1&1/2 years ago. But thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I realized that my question is related to this Question [InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 8825....](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52324322/11665352).

**Solution From that post:**
@[shaili](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10348146/shaili) posted,

In the last layer for eg you used model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax')). Here 1 restricts its value from [0, 1) change its shape to the maximum output label. For eg your output is from label [0,7) then use model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

```
input_text = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.string)
embedding = Lambda(ElmoEmbedding, output_shape=(max_len, 1024))(input_text)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True,
                   recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))(embedding)
x_rnn = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True,
                       recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))(x)
x = add([x, x_rnn])  # residual connection to the first biLSTM
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="softmax"))(x)
Here in TimeDistributed layer n_tags is the length of tags from which I want to classify.
```

If I predict some other quantity such as q_tag whose length is different from n_tags i.e suppose 10 and length of n_tags is 7 and I received 8 as output label it will give the invalid argument error Received a label value of 8 which is outside the valid range of [0, 7).

**From my experience**,
Usually, this error generates due to the, no of classifications to be classified, inaccurately. Here in my code, `model.add(Dense(6, activation = tf.nn.softmax)` I gave `6` types of classification to be generated instead of `13596`. However, this is not a fully working code, at least it gets my code running.

Comment: @Bryce Ramgovind, Edited the answer based on your suggestions. But, I've already provided reference earlier itself. Can you tell me why commenting for a post which is 1 & 1/2 years old.?